# Add up multiple value in array

Tags: php, arrays

I am looking for a quick solution to add up multiple values I have assigned in a array.

```
$cars = array(
    "name" => "cars",
    "checkout" => 5,20,40,
    "car_cost" => 240.00
);
```

I want to add up the "checkout" of the array so I can get the value of 65 to echo out on my site.

Thanks

Comment: Is `5,20,40` an array or string or something?  The syntax you've shown `"checkout" => 5,20,40` doesn't do what you think it does (see: https://eval.in/615463).

Comment: Ah, well I want 5, 20 and 40 as separate values and add them up. Is this possible in the way I'm trying to do it?

Comment: You could store those numbers as an array, then use `array_sum` to total them.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Ok thanks. I will do that. I just had in my head after reading up on arrays that I could do it this way.   I was expecting to be able to do this  `$totalCars = array_sum($cars[1]);` and that would return 65 if I did `echo $totalCars` but I guess I have it wrong.

Comment: You can do that if you set `checkout` as an array.  Your syntax isn't quite right in your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array syntax is not creating what you think it is.  What you are doing is setting the key `"checkout"` to 5.  Then you are setting the key `0` to 20 and `1` to 40.

What you really want is:

```
$cars = array(
    "name" => "cars",
    "checkout" => array(5,20,40),
    "car_cost" => 240.00
);
```

You want to save your values as an array.  Then you can do:

```
$totalCars = array_sum($cars["checkout"]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your example is incorrect, since it would not provide a value that I assume you're expecting to exemplify, however if `checkout` is a string:

```
$cars['checkout'] = explode(',', $cars['checkout']);
```

Now it'll be an array anyway, so:

```
$sum = array_sum($cars['checkout']);
```